# Duda en lectura de archivos a un vector de estructuras

Tags: c, funciones, archivo, estructuras-de-datos

Llevo comiéndome varios días la cabeza para encontrar un error en el programa, pues no me lee los datos del fichero que creo. Llevo un mes con esto de la programación (Es en lenguaje C) pues soy bastante nuevo y todo me parece muy difícil. El ejercicio dice lo siguiente:

> Se nos pide hacer un programa para gestionar un archivo con los datos
>   de los corredores y sus tiempos en una vuelta ciclista local de 5
>   etapas.
>
> El archivo contendrá la lista de ciclistas con sus nombres y ordenados
>   por número de dorsal. Después de cada nombre van la fecha (formato
>   día, mes y año) y los tiempos, expresados en horas, minutos y
>   segundos, para cada una de las etapas. Los abandonos en una
>   determinada etapa, se indica con valores nulos de tiempos en esa
>   etapa. Hacer un programa modular con funciones para:
>
> - (i)   Introducir inicialmente la lista de dorsais y nombres de los    corredores y valores nulos de tiempos en cada etapa,
> - (ii)  Leer el archivo y guardar los datos en un vector de estructuras (una por cada corredor)
> - (iii) Actualice los datos del archivo con los resultados    de la última etapa
> - (iv)  Calcular el número de abandonos incluso una determinada etapa, indicada por la fecha,
> - (v)  Determine el líder en cada momento y devuelva su nombre.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * 
 */


typedef struct {
int dorsal,h[5],min[5],seg[5],dia[5],mes[5],ano[5];
char nombre [30];
}etapas;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
etapas  corred [4];
int dec,i;

printf ("Desea introducir datos? \n 0--No 1---Si");
scanf("%i",&dec);
if (dec==1){
    escribir  (corred);
} 
printf ("Ha elegido la opción leer el archivo,procedemos con la lectura ");

leer (corred); 

for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
    printf("%s %i",corred[i].nombre,corred[i].dorsal);
}



return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void escribir ( etapas corredo [4]){
FILE *volta;
volta=fopen ("voltinha.txt","w");
int i,j;
for (i=0;i<4;i++){
    printf("Introduce o nome do corredor %i :", i+1);
    scanf("%s",corredo[i].nombre);
    printf("Introduce un dorsal para o corredor %i : ",i+1);
    scanf("%i", &corredo[i].dorsal);
    fprintf(volta," %s  %i \n", corredo[i].nombre,corredo[i].dorsal);

         for (j=0;j<5;j++){
        ( corredo[i].h[j])=0;
        ( corredo[i].min[j])=0;
        ( corredo[i].seg[j])=0;
        ( corredo[i].ano[j])=0;
        ( corredo[i].mes[j])=0;
        ( corredo[i].dia[j])=0;
        fprintf(volta,"%i  %i  %i  %i  %i  %i \n",corredo[i].ano[j],corredo[i].mes[j],corredo[i].dia[j],corredo[i].h[j],corredo[i].min[j],corredo[i].seg[j]);
    }


}
fclose(volta);
}




void leer (FILE *volta) {
etapas corredorr [4];
int i;
if ((volta=fopen("voltinha.txt","r"))==NULL){
    printf("No se ha podido abrir el archivo");
    exit(1);
}
while (feof(volta)==0){    
    fscanf(volta,"%s",corredorr[i].nombre);
    fscanf (volta,"%i",&corredorr[i].dorsal);
    i++;
    for (int j=0;j<5;j++){
        fscanf (volta,"%i",corredorr[i].ano[j]);
        fscanf (volta,"%i",corredorr[i].mes[j]);
        fscanf (volta,"%i",corredorr[i].dia[j]);
        fscanf (volta,"%i",corredorr[i].h[j]);
        fscanf (volta,"%i",corredorr[i].min[j]);
        fscanf (volta,"%i",corredorr[i].seg[j]);

    }

}
fclose(volta);
}
```

Esto es lo que llevo hasta ahora,me escribe el fichero pero no me lo lee.

Answer (score 0):

Veo dos errores que están ocasionando que hagas lecturas en valores no definidos de memoria. Uno es que en la función `void leer (FILE *volta)` no tienes inicializado el valor del contador `i` en `0`.

El otro error que veo es que en las instrucciones como esta:

```
fscanf (volta,"%i",corredorr[i].ano[j]);
```

deberás de reemplazarlo por lo siguiente:

```
fscanf (volta,"%i",&(corredorr[i].ano[j]));
```

Lo que sucede es lo siguiente, la función:

```
int fscanf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...)
```

en los argumentos adicionales (...) espera las direcciones de los elementos en donde colocar los valores obtenidos por el stream. Al tener como argumento lo siguiente:

```
corredorr[i].ano[j]
```

estas pasando un **valor** y no una **dirección**. Como el valor almacenado en tu programa para dicha variable es **0**, le estás indicando a tu programa que acceda a esa localidad de memoria.

Probablemente una notación con punteros de lo que está sucediendo aclarará lo dicho. Lo que tienes originalmente es lo siguiente:

```
corredorr[i].ano[j]corredorr[i].ano[j]
```

esto retornará un valor. Ahora, lo siguiente es lo mismo pero en notación de apuntadores:

```
*(corredorr[i].ano + j)
```

la indirección hace mas notorio el hecho de que la expresión retorna un valor. Ahora compáralo con las siguientes expresiones que son equivalentes:

```
&(corredorr[i].ano[j]);
&(*(corredorr[i].ano + j))
```

El operador `&`hace mas legible el hecho que la expresión retorna una dirección.